# set values to columns but using indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
a   b   c   d   e   
42  1   0   1   0
42  0   0   0   1   
42  0   1   0   0
42  1   1   0   0
```

I want to do something that can make all 1 in column bcde equal to column a, so it will basically be this:

```
a   b   c   d   e   
42  42  0   42  0
42  0   0   0   42   
42  0   42  0   0
42  42  42  0   0
```

so it should be something like df.loc[df['b']==1,'b'] = df['a'] but for all bcde. the whole dataframe is hundreds of columns so i can not use .loc to set values, and iloc can not set value like loc.

Comment: Try `df.loc[df['b']==1,'[b', 'c', 'd', 'e']] = df['a']`

Comment: `df.loc[:, "b":] = df.loc[:, "b":].mul(df["a"], axis=0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
You can simply use [pandas.DataFrame.where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and give it the `df["a"] Series` as replacement. This way, it will work for both numbers and strings.

```
# df is your DataFrame

# New DataFrame...
new_df = df.where(df != 1, df["a"], axis="index")

# ...or in place:
df.where(df != 1, df["a"], axis=0), inplace=True)
```